# Notifications didn't show up at specified time

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

What's wrong with this scrap of code? It should came up with an notification at specified time. I have done some testing and logging, but nothing has changed - notifications has never showed up...

NotificationService.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class NotificationService extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String link = "http://www.login.lt/apdovanojimai/";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("LOGIN 2015")
                .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.rate_at_login))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, n.build());
    }
}
```

setAlarm():

```
private void setAlarm() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotificationService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    date1.set(2015, 04, 16, 19, 00, 00);

    Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    date2.set(2015, 04, 24, 19, 00, 00);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        setAlarm();
    }
```

Comment: NotificationService is extending Activity and NOT Service

Comment: I have edited the code above, but the result it's still the same - no notification :/ Maybe I did something wrong? Take a look
http://pastebin.com/2iYiDTVV

Comment: I dont see any difference in your code than before. Anyway, extend Service and add the notification code inside onCreate(). Also, you need to declare your service in your Manifest file.

Comment: And just for the sake, dont use 00 just use 0 when settings calendar fields to zero.

Comment: I'm unhappy to say, but this didn't help either. I have declared my service in Manifest file, and put the notification code inside onCreate() just like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering setAlarm() method is in YourActivity:

```
private void setAlarm() {
 AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);//set the hour which you want
 cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);// set the minute
 cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);// set seconds
 alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

In AlarmReceiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  Context myContext;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    myContext = context;
    showNotification();

  }

 public void showNotification()
  {
    String link = "http://www.login.lt/apdovanojimai/";
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent1.setData(Uri.parse(link));
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(myContext, 0, intent1, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(myContext)
            .setContentTitle("LOGIN 2015")
            .setContentText("hello")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, n.build());
   }

}
```

Make sure you add this in your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"  />
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help! Everything works just fine, except one slight flaw - when the notification starts showing, it comes up with a blank Activity(white) screen. I'll try to fix it...

Comment: @Sharptax you are welcome. you haven't added setContentView(R.layout.your_activity) in NotificationService Activity, so you are getting white screen

Comment: Actually, I don't need the Activity to have a layout. All I need, is to show a notification on the right time with no additional layouts showed... So the layout is irrelevant.

Comment: No... Still trying to fix it.

Comment: I didn't fully understand though :/. Could you be so kind and post a live, working example? Or just some scrap of code...

Comment: @Sharptax sorry for changing the code, use this code it works faster than previous edit